# Windows 7 Print Spooler causing Word to crash

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, print-spooler

I've been looking into this problem on one of my client networks for a couple of weeks now, trying different things.

<sub>I found [this post on Microsoft Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/el-GR/officeitpro/thread/8209c380-c6d3-4f8a-a40c-f130fce6d01f) from a guy having exactly the same problem, So I thought I'd try reposting it here to see if I get any positive response. If any of you can help me I'll pass the answer on to Randy on Technet and give credit where it's due with a link, unless there are objections to that!</sub>

> I have tried everything I could find
> by searching but the searches are now
> either repeating themselves or
> saturated with unrelated solutions so
> I figured I should just ask.
>
> My domain is running windows 2k8 R2
> print server.
>
> Clients are Dell Latitudes E6410/6510,
> sony viaos, and toshiba proteges
> pushing Windows 7 pro 64bit with
> office 2k7 pro, adobe 8pro and
> networked printers (Ricoh, HP)
>
> The problem:  Print spooler will not
> be working after a computer
> start/restart or after a computer is
> disconnected from the domain.
> restarting the print spooler service
> will usually fix it and the machine
> will work fine for the rest of the day
> or until it is restarted.  I get NO
> ERROR MSG stating that print spooler
> crashed after bootup. When I check the
> services it shows that print spooler
> is started and that there are no
> problems with it but when you try to
> open printers or word they will both
> hang. restarting print spooler is the
> only way to fix it.
>
> What I already tried: different
> drivers, re-installing office,
> re-installing adobe 8 pro, replacing
> normal.dot, clearing printer
> temps/folders, registry fixes and
> system scans.  I even went as far as
> taking a laptop, doing a clean
> format/install with win7pro 64bit,
> doing all of the windows/office/adobe
> update after installing office 2k7
> pro, adobe and the printers and it
> still crashes the exact same way. Also
> tried the following and a couple more
> and none of the worked:
>
> - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpro/thread/19badfc0-5c50-4c2a-b024-92d972f71cbb
> - http://word.mvps.org/faqs/apperrors/problemsstartingword.htm
> - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921541
>
> Scenario 1: computer starts, staff
> attempts to open word and word will
> hang.  I will then force close word,
> check printers and sure enough the
> printers aren't showing. So I restart
> the printer spooler service and
> everything starts working back up.

Comment: So you're having the exact same problem, but have you tried the exact same steps to resolve it (as outlined in the post you quote)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the Clean Spool app in the Server Resource Kit? I know it is in the 2003 resource kit, not sure if it is in the 2008 RK.

I've had issues like this in the office and it appeared to be caused by a printer driver that failed to install properly (HP Univeral Printer Driver). I reinstalled the driver on the server, and then ran Clean Spool on each system that was having the stability/app crash issues. This resolved the issue for me.